# Sublime text 3 brackets highlighting like in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, sublimetext3

I use Bracket Highlight plugin, but it works properly only if cursor is located inside the brackets. If i put the cursor immediately after the closing bracket, highlighting does not work:

[image]

In Notepad++:

[image]

How to do the same in Sublime?

Comment: Best bet would probably be to make an enhancement request with the BracketHiglighter developer. https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/issues

Comment: Ths. Asked this question there.

Comment: Maybe try also SynWrite (Windows)- it has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshots, placing the cursor immediately after the closing bracket, the highlight still works. There is still a line under the bracket, however it is less visible (probably opacity is used or something).

I skimmed through the BracketHighlighter documentation, but couldn't quickly find a way to change the appearance (although I'm pretty sure this should be possible, since the plugin is pretty customisable).